# How can i set up an automated email using javascript?

Tags: javascript

When submitted the script should send an automated email to the address provided in the form which includes an acknowledgment and a link that i will modify in the future. Here is the Register Modal:

```
<!-- REGISTER MODAL -->
<div id="register" class="modal">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    <form class="modal-content animate">
        <div class="container">
            <label><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required>

            <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="pwd-repeat" required>

            <p>By creating an account you agree to out <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

            <div class="clearfix">
                <button type="submit" onclick="sendMail();" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function sendMail(){
                        alert("Your account has been Registered \nPlease look for a confirmation email sent to \n"+ email);
                        var email = document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
                        var password = document.getElementsByName('pwd')[0].value;

                        var subject = "Penguin Register Request";
                        var body = "Thank you for setting up an account by clicking this link";





                        document.getElementById('register').style.display='none';
                    }
                </script>
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>

            </div>        
        </div>    
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't send an email with js You need your js to tell a server to do it

Comment: It needs to be done from your server. And you need to have your own email account with an email provider. Then, from the server, you'll need to communicate to your provider's SMTP server. For example, [here are the docs for gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/)

Comment: Like @StephenBugsKamenar said, you can't send an email with javascript. Try using php instead.

Comment: @T.Kropalis, it's not a php vs js thing. You can definitely send emails with js lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use node.js as the backend server. Then checkout for ex: http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/07/02/send-email-node-js-express/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot send e-mails by itself.

If you don't have the option to use server backend, you might try a 3rd party e-mail service: 
https://www.formget.com/smtp-service-providers/